# Force SSL not working with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl

I have tried all of the following in my .htaccess file.

```
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
#RewriteRule ^(/(.*))?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteEngine On

# If we receive a forwarded http request from a proxy...
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http [OR]

# ...or just a plain old http request directly from the client
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =""
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

# Redirect to https version
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I have two virtual hosts on this server and neither seem to be working I have mod-rewrite enable in the httpd.conf file.  Any ideas?

Comment: If you can, put your configuration in the main file of Apache (or an included one from there) instead of `.htaccess`.  You will gain more security, more simplicity, and better performances.

Comment: Perhaps your host runs apache together with nginx so your .htaccess is bypassed for certain files?

Answer (score 0):

Using `mod_rewrite` to redirect HTTP to HTTPS isn't recommended. You should use [RedirectSSL](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL) in your virtual hosts configuration instead.

Example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example.com
   Redirect / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName example.com

    # server settings e.g ProxyPass or DocumentRoot

    SSLEngine On
    # other ssl settings
</VirtualHost>
```